# #1054 - Unknown column 'general' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem that I did not understand; why can the column not be used?  Here is my code:

```
SELECT `a`.`id`, `a`.`title`, `e`.`url` as category, 
  calc_val(`a`.`value`, `c`.`prof`, `c`.`tax`) as general, 
  `a`.`date`, `a`.`url`, 
  SUM(`d`.`stock`) as stock 
FROM (`produc` as a) 
LEFT JOIN `prod_c` as b ON `a`.`id` = `b`.`p_id` 
LEFT JOIN `p_calc` as c ON `a`.`id` = `c`.`p_id` 
LEFT JOIN `p_opt` as d ON `a`.`id` = `d`.`p_id` 
LEFT JOIN `categ` as e ON `b`.`categ_id` = `e`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `prod_aval` as `f` ON `a`.`id` = `f`.`p_id` 
WHERE `b`.`categ_id` = '1' 
  AND `a`.`active` = 'y' 
  AND `d`.`stock` >= 1 
  AND general BETWEEN '10' AND '50' 
GROUP BY `a`.`id` 
LIMIT 9

calc_val = routine:

begin
    declare value real;
    set value = v+(v*l/100);
    return value+(value*i/100);
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aliases cannot be used in the WHERE clause, so you would need to include the calculation instead:

```
AND calc_val(`a`.`value`, `c`.`prof`, `c`.`tax`) BETWEEN '10' AND '50'
```

Alternatively, you can use a derived table and apply part or all of the WHERE clause to it.  This might be useful if the calculation is costly/complex/processor intensive.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT `a`.`id`, `a`.`title`, `e`.`url` as category, 
      calc_val(`a`.`value`, `c`.`prof`, `c`.`tax`) as general, 
      `a`.`date`, `a`.`url`, 
      SUM(`d`.`stock`) as stock 
    FROM (`produc` as a) 
    LEFT JOIN `prod_c` as b ON `a`.`id` = `b`.`p_id` 
    LEFT JOIN `p_calc` as c ON `a`.`id` = `c`.`p_id` 
    LEFT JOIN `p_opt` as d ON `a`.`id` = `d`.`p_id` 
    LEFT JOIN `categ` as e ON `b`.`categ_id` = `e`.`id` 
    LEFT JOIN `prod_aval` as `f` ON `a`.`id` = `f`.`p_id` 
    WHERE `b`.`categ_id` = '1' 
      AND `a`.`active` = 'y' 
      AND `d`.`stock` >= 1 
    GROUP BY `a`.`id` 
    LIMIT 9
)
WHERE general BETWEEN '10' AND '50'
```

Answer (score 0):

The term "GENERAL" is a reserved word if you use MySql Server Version 5.5+. Have a look a this page to lern more: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html#table-reserved-words-new-5.5

HTH, Andy

Comment: I am using version 5.0 and even if I swap general for gen1 returns the same problem